# What is the difference between ずに and ない-form?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

My wife is studying for the JLPT exam, and came across the following question:

> ２時間、＿＿＿＿＿立って話しました。

She narrowed the choices down to:

1. すわらずに
2. すわらないと

Or another similar question:

> あの花は５日に＿＿＿＿＿とさきません。

1. ならず
2. ならない

In both cases, the two answers seem "correct". According to the answers 1 is correct is both cases, but many people suggested number 2 seems better.
What is the difference between ずに and ない-form? Why would the ない-form be wrong here?

Comment: We've also found [What is the difference between 〜ないではいられない and 〜ずにはいられない](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-and-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84), but it didn't quite explain it.

Comment: You might also be interested in this question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/difference-between-negative-forms-%E3%81%9A-and-%E3%81%AC

Comment: The answer for the first question should be すわらずに or すわらない"で"

Comment: Isn't it 「あの花は5日"に"（ならない）とさきません」？？？

Comment: @Chocolate, except in Western dialects it's quite common to use 座らんと立って話した :)

Comment: I did a bit of Googling, and it appears that the second example may be 「あの花は5月に_____とさきません。」. Is this correct? Source: http://cn.explore.ne.jp/study/nihongo/zhenti2007.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

～ず and ～ない mean essentially the same thing, as they are both negative forms (i.e. they both mean "not"). ず is more of a written or formal style, while ない is spoken or standard.

However, the examples in your question actually revolve around ～に and ～と, as it's a grammar usage question. Let's take a look at your examples:

> ２時間、＿＿＿＿＿立って話しました。

座【すわ】らずに is the correct answer here, and has several close analogues that could be used as well:

- 座【すわ】らなくて
- 座【すわ】らないで
- 座【すわ】ることなく

The nuances may vary slightly between these, but they all fit in the sentence grammatically, which is what these questions are designed to test.

> あの花は５月に＿＿＿＿＿とさきません。

In this example, the time (5月に) is the hint and the key is the と after the blank. Though ～ず can be followed by と, it ends up having the same meaning as ～ずに, so the answer has to be ならない, as ～ないと deals with time.

**But why?**

Though the meanings of ～ず and ～ない are basically the same, the meanings diverge when they become ～ずに and ～ないと.

- ～ずに means basically "without doing ～" (～に just turns this into an adverb, just like the で in ～ないで)
- ～ないと on the other hand, means "when not doing ～" or "if [it] doesn't ～" (～と in this case means "when" or "if")

Comment: 大辞林 has an entry for the collocation ずと: http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A8&stype=0&dtype=0

Comment: This sort of makes sense, thanks. On the second sentence, you say the answer should be ～ない because と follows it, but our book says the answer is ならず. We looked again for the answer, and it does look like you are right. Thanks!

Comment: @snailplane I stand corrected. I'll remove that from my answer. So ～ずと has the same meaning as ～ずに, according to that entry, am I understanding that correctly? Interesting.

Comment: I think the ~~ずと is old/archaic. (We still use 「言わずと知れたこと(だ/を/よ)」「~~せずとも~~ (though this is not ~ずと but ~ずとも)」etc., but these sound literary. We'd say 「言わなくても分かることだ/を」「~~しなくても~~」in normal conversation.)

Comment: @Chocolate Yeah I got that sense from the other samples I investigated, too. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

[ずに] is a conjunction particle that is used when you want to say "without (usu. doing something). [話さずに without speaking] [食べずに without eating].

[ない] is a used for negation.

[２時間、座らずに立って話しました。2hrs. of talking [standing] without sitting]

I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think ずに is normally referred to as a particle.  [大辞林](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=110464300000&pagenum=1) says it's a collocation of ず (an auxiliary verb used for negation) and the particle に.  My 集英社国語辞典 says the same thing.

Comment: Correct, it is not a particle, though it is a conjunction. Thank you for that correction.