# せず - What does it come from?

Tags: grammar, negation, auxiliary-ず

> 気にするまいと思っても、気に**せず**にはいられない。

In above sentence, I guess `せず` means `しない`, but what is the original form, and how does it become `せず`?

Comment: Mildly related reading: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12644/. See also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/235/ and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2840/.

Comment: @senshin The 2nd link is very useful.

Comment: The second link probably needs another answer…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-ず` form of a verb means "without doing" and is roughly equivalent to `ないで`. It's not a contraction of anything and is a verb form on its own.

The `-ず` form is formed by taking the `-ない` form of a verb and replacing the `-ない` with `-ず`. For the irregular verbs, `する` becomes `せず` and `[来]{く}る` becomes `[来]{こ}ず`.

Answer (score 9):

> what is the original form

The verb する.

> and how does it become せず?

ず is an auxiliary verb ([助動詞]{じょどうし}) which attaches to the [未然形]{みぜんけい} of the verb. [せ is one 未然形 of する](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8#.E3.81.99.E3.82.8B.EF.BC.88.E5.8F.A3.E8.AA.9E.EF.BC.89) and is the one which ず attaches to.