# what does 'が入らず' mean?

Tags: definitions, auxiliary-ず

全身に力が入らず- what does '力が入らず' mean? I know 力 means strength, but what does 'が入らず' mean?

I've done some googling and it either means without strength or filled with strength. That's why I'm very clueless right now.

If possible, can I get the meaning of 'が入らず' and the meaning of 'が入らず' in this sentence's concept if it contains another meaning?

Thanks guys!

Comment: 入らず is the ず conjugation of 入る. It is a form of negation. Don't trust me on this, but my interpretation of your sentence would be "I don't have any strength left in my body".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [せず - What does it come from?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/%e3%81%9b%e3%81%9a-what-does-it-come-from)

Comment: @Garbaz ah tysm!!!

Comment: @Shurim ah ic thanks so much for your help!